# Why does this no syntax error nested class program produce garbage output, and how do I fix it?

Tags: g++, c++17, clang++

The following code includes a complete description of the problem as a TODO.
Included are cut/pasteable command lines to compile the code (without error).
Child instances contain their own name, and the initializer should copy it.
Child instances also contain a pointer to their Parent this instance.
Neither of these should print garbage.
Child also uses its Parent instance pointer to print the parent name.
This name is initialized by the Parent ctor, and so should not print as garbage.
I even ran it through clang with -fsyntax-only, without reported warning/error.
I must be missing something.  Help would be appreciated.

```
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// #####     ##    #####   ######  #    #   #####           ####   #####   #####
// #    #   #  #   #    #  #       ##   #     #            #    #  #    #  #    #
// #    #  #    #  #    #  #####   # #  #     #            #       #    #  #    #
// #####   ######  #####   #       #  # #     #     ###    #       #####   #####
// #       #    #  #   #   #       #   ##     #     ###    #    #  #       #
// #       #    #  #    #  ######  #    #     #     ###     ####   #       #
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// A class having access to all nested class instances and vice versa
// 0. presence by name in a set
// 1. by name          in a map
// 2. by index         in a vector
// 3. by name to index in a map
// and nested classes have access to parent and to each other through parent.
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// TODO produce the following instead of garbage output.
// Compile and expected output:
// $ g++ --std=c++17 -Wall -pedantic -o parent parent.cpp
// $ ./parent
// P:A
// P:B
// $ 
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <set>

using namespace std;

// Utility function for when things go wrong.
template<class... Args> void panic(Args... args) {
    cerr << "parent panic: ";
    (cerr << ... << args) << "\n";
    exit(1);
}

class Parent { public: //CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC

    class Child { public: //cccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc
        Child(Parent* p, const string& n) : parent(p), name(n) {} // Child ctor
        ~Child() {}                                               // Child dtor
        void operator()(){ cout<<parent->name<<':'<<name<<endl; } // Child ftor

        Parent*     parent; // Child Parent ptr
        const string& name; // Child name
    }; //ccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc

    Parent(const string& name) : name(name) {}                // Parent ctor
    ~Parent() {}                                              // Parent dtor
    void operator()() { for(auto child: vcci) { child(); } }  // Parent ftor

    void operator+=(const vector<string>& names) {
        for(auto name : names) {
            if (used.find(name) != used.end()) panic(name, " re-used,");
            used.insert(name);             // Fast search
            size_t vcN = vcci.size();      // Index for next name
            vcci.emplace_back(this, name); // construct child into vector
            Child* back = &(vcci[vcN]);    // Address of child to store
            mptr[name] = back;             // Store address of child
            mint[name] = vcN;              // map name to index
        }
    }

    string name;              // name of parent
    set<string> used;         // fast lookup of name for duplicates
    vector<Child> vcci;       // vector of emplaced Child instances
    map<string, Child*> mptr; // name lookup of Child pointer
    map<string, size_t> mint; // index of name

}; //CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC

//eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee
void experiment() {
    vector<string> AB = { "A", "B" };  // Names to use as Child names
    Parent parent("P");                // Named parent
    parent += AB;                      // Produce named Child instances
    parent();                          // Execute parent ftor
}

//mmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmm
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    experiment();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Valid syntax only means that the compiler could parse it. It does not mean that the code doesn't contain flaws or logic errors. What does stepping through the code in a debugger tell you is happening?

Comment: I will try, but my gdb skills are ancient and need refreshing.

Comment: Time to refresh those skills, then. There's no better tool to use for solving problems with your code. Using the debugger is a skill that needs to stay polished. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `for(auto name : names) ...`, `name` is a local variable that's a copy of the string from the vector. That variable is created and destroyed on each iteration of the loop. Then you create `Child` instances with `name` as an argument - they store a reference to that variable in their `name` member. Soon afterwards, the variable is destroyed and all those references become dangling.

By the time the program actually tries to use `Child::name` members, the strings are long gone, and the references are long dangling. Any attempt to use them exhibits undefined behavior, by way of accessing an object after its lifetime has ended.

Answer (score 0):

```
const string& name; // Child name
```

This was the offending line.
It had to be a string, not a string reference.
Simple programmer error.
Thanks for reviewing and pointing me in a good direction.